Questions about the inequality ${\text{dim}}_k k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}\leq d_1d_2\cdots d_n\quad $
The following are from Froberg's "Introduction to Grobner bases" , and Hungerford's undergraduate "Abstract Algebra" text.
Background
Theorem 1: $k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n]\backsimeq (k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}])[x_n]$
Theorem 2:  Let $K$ be an extension field of $F$ and $u\in K$ an algebraic element over $F$ with minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$.  Then
$(1)$ $F(u)\equiv F(x)/(p(x))$
$(2)$ $\{1_F,u,u^2,\ldots,u^{n-1}\}$ is a basis of the vector space $F(u)$ over $F$.
$(3)$ $[F(u):F]=n$.
Assumed Exercise: Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal generated by monomials in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  Show that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$ if and only if for each $i$ there is a $d_i>0$, such that ${x_i^{d_i}}\in \mathfrak{a}$.
Exercise: Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a monomial ideal such that $\{x_i^{d_i},\cdots,{x_n^{d_n}}\}$ is a part of a minimal system of generators for $\mathfrak{a}$, where $d_i$ are positive.  Show that
$$(LHS)\quad d_1+\cdots d_n-n+1 \leq {\text{dim}}_k  k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}\leq d_1d_2\cdots d_n\quad (RHS)$$
Questions
This is a following from this post on the solution to Assumed Exercise above: Showing that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$ assuming basic linear algebra and min amount of abs alg.
I am trying to do the above Exercise using the Assumed Exercise & Basic Abstract Algebra.
The difficulties I have with the right hand side inequality:
For the $(RHS)$ inequality, I am not sure how the number $d_1\cdot d_2\cdot \cdots\cdot d_n$ is arrived at.
I know it has to do with the number of bases elements and that it is allowed for over-counting of the identity element.
Furthermore, for the $n$ different bases, we have $\{1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]},x_1,x_1^2,\ldots,x_1^{{d_1}-1}\}\cap \{1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]},x_2,x_2^2,\ldots,x_2^{{d_2}-1}\}\cap\cdots\cap \{1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]},x_n,x_n^2,\ldots,x_n^{{d_n}-1}\}=\{1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]}\}$.
I am not sure how to proceed from here on.
Can someone explain it to me without making reference to any ideas from affine algebraic sets, algebraic varieties or anything from Groebner bases.
I am trying to do this question with ideas from basic abstract algebra and assuming a basic course from linear algebra.
Thank you in advance

Well, the basic idea is that there is a common multiple of all the monomial generators of degree at most $\prod_i d_i$.  (It's a very sloppy bound.)

@EricTowers I don't understand what you mean when you say: "...there is a common multiple of all the monomial generators of degree..."  Each $d_i$s counts the number of elements for each $x_i^{d_i}$ for each $i=1,2,3,\ldots n$?

Note that for all $i$, $x_i^{d_i}$ divides $\prod_i x_i^{d_i}$.

@EricTowers thank you for the clarification. Can i also trouble you with the post  It has to do with the solution to the LHS inequality to this post. When I wrote this post,it was in a single post, but I thought it migght be better that I split it up asking about the two different side about of an inequality.  Thank youi n advance.
